# How can I automatically calculate and change numbers in a text file (Java class)?

Tags: vim, text-manipulation

Suppose I have an enum class like [the one from Oracle’s example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters
    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    private double mass() { return mass; }
    private double radius() { return radius; }

    // universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    public static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }
    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }
    //...
```

I need to multiply all of the numbers in the class by 0.33. I don’t want to code the calculation in the enum, but to change the text itself. What’s the fastest way to automate this in Vim / IDEA / any other tool?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I don't think you're going to find a general-purpose answer; mathematical operations on source-code constants are so uncommon I doubt anybody has support for it (except maybe Emacs, but Emacs has Tetris and a psychiatrist built in).

Comment: I believe it's doable in vim using a vim macro but I'm not (yet) fluent in vim enough to formulate the macro.

Comment: This isn't really a java or enums question

Comment: I accept, tags removed.

Comment: I actually don't need to calculate exponents, only whole integer and floats. The java example wasn't the best text to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vim, I would attempt the following:

```
:% s /\(\d\+\.\d\+\)/\=(submatch(1) * 0.33)/gc
```

This will match each number (\d+.\d+) in the entire file (%) and substitute (s) it with the results (\=) of multiplying (*) the matched number (submatch(1)) by 0.33.

Comment: I actually don't need exponents, but I do need to handle whole number (without .) too. I guess with some modifications this can be the solution for my need.

Comment: It's true, you caught me there.  It does not _actually_ handle the exponent correctly which could result in a denormalized representation of the number.

Comment: Someone answered and deleted the following line:  :%s/[0-9.]\+/\=submatch(0) * 0.33/g    which detect integers too, but have alot of false positives

Comment: @Dave'stux I was the one who deleted that.  Did that help you?  I can read add if it did, but it also did not work for exponents.

Comment: @fvrghl I don't need the exponents, I shouldn't have used that example. however your solution changed every occurrence of a '.' in the file.

Comment: So you want 2.4e6 to become 1.6e1.98?  If so, this should work:

    :% s /\(\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?\)/\=(submatch(1) * 0.33)/gc

This makes the decimal portion optional

Comment: @kjelderg I get: E486: Pattern not found: (\d\+(\.\d\+)\?)

Comment: My apologies, a couple slashes got lost somewhere:  That should have been :% s /\\(\d\+\\(\.\d\+\\)\?\\)/\=(submatch(1) * 0.33)/gc

Answer (score 1):

If you go the macro route, this is one way to replace a visually selected number with itself multiplied by 0.33:

```
c
<C-r>=
<C-r>"
*0.33
<CR>
```

Comment: This is working. but because the class is very long this approach will require a lot of labour. Ultimately the macro will include a search and visual select for the next number.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to python for this one. Consider the following script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

numeric_const_pattern = r"""
[-+]? # optional sign
(?:
    (?: \d* \. \d+ ) # .1 .12 .123 etc 9.1 etc 98.1 etc
    |
    (?: \d+ \.? ) # 1. 12. 123. etc 1 12 123 etc
)
# followed by optional exponent part if desired
(?: [Ee] [+-]? \d+ ) ?
"""
rx = re.compile(numeric_const_pattern, re.VERBOSE)

with open('code.txt') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        num = rx.findall(line)
        for n in num:
            line = line.replace(n, str(float(n)*.33))
        print line.rstrip()
```

Output:

```
$ ./num.py 
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (1.08999e+23, 805101.0),
    VENUS   (1.60677e+24, 1997094.0),
    EARTH   (1.97208e+24, 2104786.2),
    MARS    (2.11893e+23, 1121076.0),
    JUPITER (6.27e+26,   23592360.0),
    SATURN  (1.87704e+26, 19888440.0),
    URANUS  (2.86638e+25, 8434470.0),
    NEPTUNE (3.3792e+25, 8166180.0);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters
    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    private double mass() { return mass; }
    private double radius() { return radius; }

    // universal gravitational constant  (m0.99 kg-0.33 s-0.66)
    public static final double G = 2.20209e-11;

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }
    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }
```

Not perfect, since all numbers basically get multiplied with `0.33`.
`kg-1` gets transformed into `kg-0.33` etc. But it's a start.
Next step is to ignore comments and reduce false positives...